# How can I identify which solution triggered the WhenEvent?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I am using `NDSolve` for problems like this:

```
sols = NDSolve[{(1 + 25 Exp[- u[s]^2] u[s]^2) u'[s]^2 == u[s]^2, u[0] == 0.5,
   WhenEvent[u[s] == 4, "StopIntegration"]}, u, {s, 0, 20}]

Plot[u[s] /. sols, {s, 0, 5}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

There are multiple solution branches, I am only interested in the one which was stopped by the `WhenEvent`, i.e. the one which reaches $u=4$ for some value of $s$.

Is there a convenient way to restrict the solution set to only those ones for which the `WhenEvent` was triggered?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very scalable answer, but what about something like `Select[u /. sols, #[#["Domain"][[1, 2]]] == 4 &]` ?

Comment: @ChipHurst, it might be the best way nevertheless. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be useful if your actual event is more complicated, use a discrete variable as a flag:

```
sols = NDSolve[{(1 + 25 Exp[-u[s]^2] u[s]^2) u'[s]^2 == u[s]^2, 
   u[0] == 0.5, a[0] == 1,
   WhenEvent[u[s] == 4, a[s] -> 0], 
   WhenEvent[a[s] == 0, "StopIntegration"]
        }, {u, a}, {s, 0, 20}, 
     DiscreteVariables -> {a[s]}]

u /. Select[sols, Last@((a /. #)["ValuesOnGrid"]) == 0 &]
```

I think the method suggested by @ChipHurst in comment is better for this example though.